# Xamarin.Forms unable to bind ObservableCollection to CollectionList via ViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding, collectionview

I have this issue where first I initialize my ShoppingViewModel (from Command in another ViewModel)

With my ShoppingViewModel - I call out a method GetProducts that creates a collection of Products and then it navigates to the ShoppingView - where I attempt to bind this collection to the collection view.

Where it fails is to bind one to another.

It works fine if I pass the collection to the view via the constructor and manually attach it to the ItemSource Property of CollectionView;

I looked up several articles on this, and even sat through several Udemy courses to resolve this where I would try and change this to listview(from collection view and play around with binding context) - nothing seems to work - I am not sure where I am going wrong;

I also tried to see if changing binding context reference would help - please help me understand where I am going wrong with this

XAML for Shopping View is below

```
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"  
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"    
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:FurniturePhoneApp.ViewModel"
         x:Class="FurniturePhoneApp.View.ShoppingView"
 >

<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <vm:ShoppingViewModel  x:Key="vm" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<ContentPage.Content BindingContext="{StaticResource vm}">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Below is the selection of our products"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />


        <CollectionView  x:Name="CvProducts"
                            SelectionMode="Single"
                            SelectionChanged="CvProducts_SelectionChanged"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                                     Span="2"
                                     VerticalItemSpacing="20"
                                     HorizontalItemSpacing="0" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.Header>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Margin="15,50,15,15"
                               Text="Explore"
                               FontAttributes="Bold"
                               FontSize="Title"
                               TextColor="#2C2C2C" />
                    <CollectionView  x:Name="CvCategories"
                                         HeightRequest="200"
                                         SelectionMode="Single"
                                         SelectionChanged="CvCategories_SelectionChanged">
                        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                            <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Frame Padding="0"
                                               BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                               Margin="15,0,15,0"
                                               HasShadow="True">
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                            <Frame Padding="0"
                                                       CornerRadius="15"
                                                       IsClippedToBounds="True"
                                                       HeightRequest="150"
                                                       WidthRequest="150"
                                                       HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                                <Image Aspect="AspectFit"
                                                           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                                           VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                                           Source="{Binding FullImageUrl}"/>
                                            </Frame>
                                            <Label TextColor="#2C2C2C"
                                                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                                       FontSize="Medium"
                                                       Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </Frame>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    </CollectionView>

                    <Label Margin="15,15,15,0"
                               Text="Trending Products"
                               TextColor="#2C2C2C"
                               FontSize="Title"
                               FontAttributes="Bold" />
                </StackLayout>
            </CollectionView.Header>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Spacing="0">
                        <Frame CornerRadius="10"
                                   HasShadow="False"
                                   Margin="15,0,15,0"
                                   Padding="20">
                            <StackLayout Spacing="5"
                                             Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Image Aspect="Fill"
                                           HeightRequest="120"
                                           Source="{Binding FullImageUrl}"/>
                                <Label TextColor="#2C2C2C"
                                           Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                <Label TextColor="#FA6400"
                                           Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='${0}'}"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage.Content>
```

and my ShoppingViewModel is below

```
namespace FurniturePhoneApp.ViewModel
{
    public class ShoppingViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ProductByCategory> Products;

        public ShoppingViewModel()
        {
            GetProducts();
        }

        public async void GetProducts()
        {
            var items = await ApiService.GetProductByCategory(2);

            ObservableCollection<ProductByCategory> Products = new ObservableCollection<ProductByCategory>();
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                Products.Add(item);
            }

            if (Products != null)
            {
                // await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new ShoppingView());
                await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new ShoppingView(Products));
            }

        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new local variable inside your `GetProducts` method. You can just comment that line and creat the `ObservableCollection` where you declare your varaible

```
    public ObservableCollection<ProductByCategory> Products = new ObservableCollection<ProductByCategory>();

    public ShoppingViewModel()
    {
        GetProducts();
    }

    public async void GetProducts()
    {
        var items = await ApiService.GetProductByCategory(2);

        //ObservableCollection<ProductByCategory> Products = new ObservableCollection<ProductByCategory>();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Products.Add(item);
        }

        if (Products != null)
        {
            // await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new ShoppingView());
            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new ShoppingView(Products));
        }

    }
```

You tried a lot of places where you set your binding context, I usually do (my personal preference)

1. In the XAML (without the resource thing that you did)

   ```
   <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:IsNullOrEmptyConverterViewModel />
   </ContantPage.BindingContext
   ```
2. Or in the page Constructor

   ```
   public myNewPage()
   {
   BindingContext = new ViewModel();
   InitializeComponent();
   }
   ```